# Evaluating a set of expressions under button control with voice annotation

Tags: gui-construction, sound

For example, let us assume that a user clicks the button named "Evaluate" and then a voice announces "Please wait your expression is being evaluated". *Mathematica* then carries out set of instructions and finally announces "Your Answer is so and so".

I tried

```
Button["Evaluate",
Speak["Please provide the inputs"];
Pause[2];
a = Input["Enter value
1)For Cantiliver 
2)For Simply Supported"];
If[a == 1, Speak["Calculating for Cantiliver"],
Speak["Calculating for Supported Beam"];
(* Calculations *)
Speak["Answer is"];
Method -> Queued]]
```

1)I didn't also understand the purpose of `Method->Queued`.

2)If I don't use `;` after `Speak[]` how is it interpreted

Comment: Hi. What means " and then"? So pressed or clicked? Have you tried anything? Take a look at `Button` and don't forget `Method->"Queued"`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because its unclear what you are asking, Try do do better, please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a minimum example of the code you are working on in [properly formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess OP wants to read out the result of the "set of instructions":

```
Button["Evaluate",
    Module[{res},
        Speak["Please wait your expression is being evaluated"];
        res = Integrate[1/(x^3 + 1), x];
        Speak["Your Answer is"];
        Pause[0.1];
        Speak[res];
        Pause[0.1];
        Speak["period"]
        ],
    Method -> "Queued"
    ]
```

Comment: What is the use of Method->"Queued". I read in documentation about (By default, button functions are evaluated on a preemptive link, which times out after 5 seconds). What is the other type of method that alters the code.

Comment: @Sai `Method->"Queued"` will force the evaluation be executed on the "main" process, in a synchronization fashion, so if your code need more than 5sec to finish, it will not timeout.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Button["Evaluate",
 Speak["Let me think..."];
 Pause[3];  (* Here all the task code *)
 Speak["I shall learn to make good questions and show my own efforts"];
 SystemOpen["http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask"]
 , Method -> "Queued"]
```